# Image processing in C++

Tags: c++, image-processing

If I want to work with images in C++ like reading and displaying them, in addition to making some operations on them, where do you recommend someone to start? Are there specific libraries you recommend using for image processing for example?

Thanks.

Comment: You need to be more specific, "make some operations on them" is extremely vague..

Comment: This question is hopelessly vague.  What sort of images?  Where would you be getting them, and what would you want to do with them?  Any particular format?  "Images" and "operations" covers a whole lot of ground.

Comment: Why the votes to close as "not a real question"? That's silly. I could have understood "duplicate".

Comment: @Eugen, @David: if the question seems hopelessly vague to you, then that can only be because of a lack of knowledge of the domain.

Comment: A combination of IPP and OpenCV is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 7):

I've understood [OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/) to be a great imaging library, and can be used with a handful of languages (one of which is C++).

Answer (score 2):

Intel has a very strong library: http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/

I've been using Cimg http://cimg.sourceforge.net/ which was easy to use.

Comment: What do you recommend of those to start with?

Comment: A friend and I used Cimg for our diploma thesis. I found it pretty self explanatory. It served our needs. I never used opencv but I've heard that it is extensive.

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of C++ image handling and image processing libraries. @fbrereto mentions OpenCV, but note that OpenCV is geared towards *computer vision*, and as such is not very convenient for simplest things. It also relies on coding techniques that are technically Undefined Behavior, such as just giving a hot damn about alignment requirements, but it has some nifty algorithms for vision work.

ImageMagick is a good allround image handling library. I used it some ten years ago. At that time, though, it had a problem with loading JPEGs, where it just asserted out on error, instead of producing an exception.

Also, Boost has functionality for image processing, but not display.

On Windows platform you can use GDI++.

Not sure about platform-specific libraries for other platforms.

Cheers & hth.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely look into CxImage. If I am not mistaken, it is used in a number of applications that do some graphic image processing, and can be readily used from or incorporated int other applications.